# Oracle SQL combine 2 selects to one column

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry if this sounds vague ... I have searched for the answer for this but, am finding it hard to explain - therefore hard to search for.

I have a really simple script...

```
select pr1.polypart_no match_from, pr1.part_no match_to
from oes_polybox_replace pr1
where pr1.plant = 'W'
and pr1.part_no = 
      (select max(pr2.part_no) 
          from oes_polybox_replace pr2 
          where pr2.plant = 'W' 
          and pr2.polypart_no = 'YPOLYGREY')
```

...that shows in column 1, a part number and in column 2, a generic part that can be used in place of the part number in column 1.

[image]

My issues is I need to add the part in column 2 to column 1, i.e.

[image]

Is there a way a add 2 select's to one column?

Comment: By add do you mean `Y450168` and `Y453485` becomes `Y450168Y453485` ? it is not clear from your image

Comment: @ SearchAndResQ ... sorry, no not Y450168Y453485. Y453485 needs to become another part (a unique row)  in the column 1 list.

Comment: If you merely want everything in MATCH_TO to also be in the MATCH_FROM column, then yes, you can "UNION" two queries together.  Would you like an example of that?

Comment: A Union example would be great please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a union example

```
select pr1.polypart_no match_from
from oes_polybox_replace pr1
where pr1.plant = 'W'
and pr1.part_no = 
      (select max(pr2.part_no) 
          from oes_polybox_replace pr2 
          where pr2.plant = 'W' 
          and pr2.polypart_no = 'YPOLYGREY')
UNION
select pr1.part_no match_from
from oes_polybox_replace pr1
where pr1.plant = 'W'
and pr1.part_no = 
      (select max(pr2.part_no) 
          from oes_polybox_replace pr2 
          where pr2.plant = 'W' 
          and pr2.polypart_no = 'YPOLYGREY')
```

UNION only selects distinct values, UNION ALL does not.

You could wrap this up further if you need to re-order.

```
SELECT match_from from (
select pr1.polypart_no match_from
    from oes_polybox_replace pr1
    where pr1.plant = 'W'
    and pr1.part_no = 
          (select max(pr2.part_no) 
              from oes_polybox_replace pr2 
              where pr2.plant = 'W' 
              and pr2.polypart_no = 'YPOLYGREY')
    UNION
    select pr1.part_no match_from
    from oes_polybox_replace pr1
    where pr1.plant = 'W'
    and pr1.part_no = 
          (select max(pr2.part_no) 
              from oes_polybox_replace pr2 
              where pr2.plant = 'W' 
              and pr2.polypart_no = 'YPOLYGREY')) tab
order by match_from asc
```